# How to call function randomly in c# according to checkbox list selection value?

Tags: c#, logic

Checkbox List has n items, then combination of selection of items has various logic.
e.g. 4 items in list, then user can select 1, 2 ,3 or 4 items.

1. when 1 items selected possible case is 4

   - ->if items[0] selected then (random_function[0])
   - ->if items[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj64k.png) selected then (random_function[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj64k.png))

.
.so on

2. when 2 items selected possible case is 6

   - ->if items[0] & items[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj64k.png) then select (random_function[0] or random_function[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj64k.png))
   - ->if items[0] & items[2] then select (random_function[0] or random_function[2])

.
.so on

3. when 3 items selected possible case is 3

   - ->if items[0] & items[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj64k.png) & items[2] then select (random_function[0] or random_function[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj64k.png) or random_function[2])
   - ->if items[0] & items[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj64k.png) & items[3] then select (random_function[0] or random_function[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj64k.png) or random_function[3])

.
.so on

4. when 4 items selected possible case is 1

   - ->if items[0] & items[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj64k.png) & items[2] & items[4]  then select (random_function[0] or random_function[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj64k.png) or random_function[2] or random_function[3])

Note.: random_function[i] call randomly

so, each items has each *if* cases, 
it is possible for small number of n, what if value of n is greater than 10 or 20.

I tried for n=4 (checklistbox items) but i have to try for n=15.

How to call these function according items selected combinations.

[image]

And following code in button click event:
`

```
string s = null;
            int c = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
                {
                    c = c + 1;
                }
            }
            if (c == 1)
            {
                if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0))
                { s = " Item one"; }
                else if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(1))
                { s = " Item two "; }
                else if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(2))
                { s = " Item three "; }
                else if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(3))
                { s = " Item four "; }
            }
            else if (c == 2)
            {
                Random r = new Random();
                int var = r.Next(1, 3);
                if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) && checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(1))
                {
                    if (var == 1) { s = " Item one "; }
                    else { s = " Item two "; }
                }
                else if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) && checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(2))
                {
                    if (var == 1) { s = " Item one "; }
                    else { s = " Item three "; }
                }
                else if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) && checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(3))
                {
                    if (var == 1) { s = " Item one "; }
                    else { s = " Item four "; }
                }
                else if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(1) && checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(2))
                {
                    if (var == 1) { s = " Item two "; }
                    else { s = " Item three "; }
                }
                else if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(1) && checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(3))
                {
                    if (var == 1) { s = " Item two "; }
                    else { s = " Item four "; }
                }
                else if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(2) && checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(3))
                {
                    if (var == 1) { s = " Item three "; }
                    else { s = " Item four "; }
                }
            }
            else if (c == 3)
            {
                Random r = new Random();
                int var = r.Next(1, 4);
                if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) && checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(1) && checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(2))
                {
                    if (var == 1) { s = " Item one "; }
                    else if (var == 2) { s = " Item two "; }
                    else { s = " Item three "; }
                }
                else if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) && checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(1) && checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(3))
                {
                    if (var == 1) { s = " Item one "; }
                    else if (var == 2) { s = " Item two "; }
                    else { s = " Item three "; }
                }
                else if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(1) && checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(2) && checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(3))
                {
                    if (var == 1) { s = " Item one "; }
                    else if (var == 2) { s = " Item two "; }
                    else { s = " Item three "; }
                }
            }
            else if (c == 4)
            {
                Random r = new Random();
                int var = r.Next(1, 4);
                if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) && checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(1) && checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(2) && checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(3))
                {
                    if (var == 1) { s = " Item one "; }
                    else if (var == 2) { s = " Item two "; }
                    else if (var == 3) { s = " Item three "; }
                    else { s = " Item four "; }
                }
            }
            label1.Text = s; //output
```

`

Comment: Are you able to share the code you have so far relating to this.

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Your description is complicated. You need to show screenshots of your UI and include your code - then we can set up the same project at our end and give you a solution. Right now it's just too darn hard to try to decipher.